# SSL issues with puppetdb

Tags: nginx, ssl, puppet, puppetmaster, puppetdb

I'm setting up Puppetdb with SSL and having issues with certificates.

I'm using Nginx as an SSL proxy for Puppet, so my CA is managed by a mongrel server on this Nginx proxy machine.

If I generate a certificate for my Puppetdb URI using the CA on the Nginx machine, I'm able to setup the Puppetdb using the `puppetlabs-puppetdb` module (since the Puppet agent uses the proxy's CA), but then the Puppetmaster cannot connect to it, because it has its own CA certificate which is generates itself.

If I generate a certificate for the Puppetdb URI using one of the Puppetmasters, I cannot deploy the Puppetdb using the `puppetlabs-puppetdb` module since the Puppet agent doesn't use the same CA certificate.

What could I do to reconcile all this? Can I full turn off SSL on my puppetmasters (since SSL is managed by the Nginx proxy) and have them use the proxy's CA to connect to the Puppetdb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using a wrong setup for my puppetmasters, namely, letting them create their own CA in a separate directory. [This link](http://bodepd.com/wordpress/?p=7) cleared it up. I now:

- Use the same directory in agent and master mode (in my case, the standard `/var/lib/puppet/ssl` directory). This ensures that it uses the same CA for both modes;
- Use `ca=false` on the puppetmaster (section `master`) so the puppetmaster won't complain about using another CA than his own;
- Stop specifying `certname=` for puppetmasters and let them use the machine's name as done in agent mode.